Is there anyway I can dynamically create Superset Role with specific permissions by system call?
We have an application which would like to use Superset's dashboard to show our business analytics. We hold a Superset deployment in K8S node. When the application is running, we call Superset APIs to import datasets, charts and dashboards. We would like to create roles with specific datasets permissions dynamically by system call.
We find that Superset does not provide such APIs. We can connect to Superset pod to execute scripts, but did not find Superset CLI for this. Is there anyway I can dynamically create Superset Role with specific permissions by system call?
